# Python Etsy API - How can I update listing attributes?

Tags: python, json, api, etsy

I am using python etsy API to create and update listings. I have been able to create a listing, upload images and update inventory. However I have not been able to update a listing's attributes. I believe this is because python does not have integer arrays which is what the function wants as a parameter. I've tried passing a list of strings instead but the attribute appears in etsy with the apostrophe &#39 instead of just the string. I think it also deletes previous attributes if you populate new ones. Anyways, here is my code:

```
attribute1 = {'property_id': property_id, 'property_name': 'Room', 'scale_id': None, 'scale_name': None, 'value_ids': [2355, 3946, 2352, 2358, 2353], 'values': ["Patio & outdoor", "Dorm", "Office", "Nursery", "Entryway"]}

etsy.updateAttribute(listing_id= listing_id, property_id= attribute1['property_id'], value_ids= attribute1['value_ids'], values= attribute1['value_ids'])
```

And this is the error I get:

```
ValueError: Could not decode response from Etsy as JSON: status_code: 400, text: "Expected int value for 'value_ids' (got 'string')."
```

Comment: Are you using a library?  If so which one?

Comment: Yes, etsy2==0.7.0
https://pypi.org/project/etsy2/

Answer (score 0):

Can with updateAttribute

and value_ids like - $param['value_ids'][0] = 246;

also take a look - property value - is_multivalued
seems need is_multivalued = true
for add multivalues

tested with PHP https://github.com/inakiabt/etsy-php
and some confusion with updateAttribute
:(